# How can I expand a dynamic range with blanks between cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to define a dynamic range that will expand the rows and columns of my range whenever a new row or column is inserted. My current formula does not want to expand to cell `$T$13`. My headers start in row `$M$7`. How can I adjust my formula?

**Formula Being Used**

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$M$8,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$M:$M),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))`

I need my range to expand to cell `$T$13`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your formula counts the number of text values in column M.

That is not a robust approach because column M contains only five text values, but columns S and T have many more values.

If you don't know which column may have the most number of entries, you can introduce a helper cell in each column that counts the number of entries below. I suggest you insert a new row 2. In column M, for example, put a formula in M2

```
=counta($M$3:M$99999)
```

Copy that formula across to column T.

Next you can evaluate which of the columns has the largest number

```
=max(M2:T2)
```

This can be plugged into your original formula like this:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$M$8,0,0,max(M2:T2),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))
```

So now, instead of just looking at how many rows are in column M, the formula uses the maximum number of rows in the columns M to S.

You can now hide row 2 if it upsets your worksheet design.

Edit: the mere count of text values with CountA will ignore blank cells and will return incorrect results. You really need a formula to find the row number of the last populated cell in each column.

This should really be a new question, but here goes

If the column has number values you can use

```
=MATCH(99^99,B5:B999,1)
```

If the column has text values you can use

```
=MATCH("zzz",C5:C999,1)
```

Adjust your ranges accordingly.

Comment: @teyln the data in my example is expanded up to `T13`, but what if I added another column for Dates, would I need to expand `=max(M2:T2)`? Any way of solving this without knowing the last column or row?

Comment: No. If you use the correct formula in row 2 it will return the number you need in the OFFSET. Read my post again. I made an edit to catch empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution mentioned by @tevlyn.

In range`$M2:$T2`

I have the follolwing formula `=IFERROR(MATCH(99^99,M$8:M$999,1),0)`.

I've added `IFERROR` because my data doesn't always have data stretched to `$T2`.

I then defined my range in name manager using:

`=OFFSET(Sheet3!$M$8,0,0,MAX(Sheet3!$M$2:$T$2),COUNTA(Sheet3!$1:$1))`

This still works even if there are blanks in between the range.